# I have tried every method to return JSON encoded PHP objects - why won't it work?

Tags: javascript, php, json

**Solution:**

Essentially, there isn't one. The $_Sock is a resource, and thus cannot be passed through json_encode(). Unfortunately, the connection is being established via a $.post, which means that it cannot be held across multiple pages (unless going to the trouble of using an application server as Jon suggested.)

Establishing the connection each time is of no particular inconvenience; it is merely an annoyance that can be tolerated. I will have to rely on a model that reestablishes the connection each time in order to send commands over the RCON server.

Thank you to Ryan and Jon for their immense help!

---

**Original Post:**

---

I have tried `dataType: 'json'`, `$.parseJSON()`, and `Header("Content-type: application/json")`, but when I try to return a `json_encode()` array or object, I am met with this error:

```
    Warning: json_encode(): type is unsupported, encoded as null
```

Here is the JavaScript $.post:

```
    $.post("rcon.php",
    {
        ip:server.ip,
        port:server.rcon.port,
        pwd:server.rcon.pwd
    },
    function(data){
        alert(data);
        $("#output").val($("#output").val()+data+"\n");
    });
```

...and here is the PHP that returns the data:

```
    $r = new minecraftRcon($rconServer, $rconPort, $rconPass);
    if ($r->Auth()) { $response = "Authenticated."; } else { $response = "Authentication failed."; }
    echo json_encode($r);
```

I have been at this for 3 hours. I simply do not understand what I need to do to get this to work. I have tried `gettype`, and it affirms that the data is indeed an object. `json_encode` should accept it, yet it is 'unsupported.' Please help - I am losing my sanity.

---

var_dump($r):

```
    <pre class='xdebug-var-dump' dir='ltr'>
    <b>object</b>(<i>minecraftRcon</i>)[<i>1</i>]
      <i>public</i> 'Password' <font color='#888a85'>=&gt;</font> <small>string</small><font color='#cc0000'>'derp'</font> <i>(length=4)</i>
      <i>public</i> 'Host' <font color='#888a85'>=&gt;</font> <small>string</small> <font color='#cc0000'>'localhost'</font> <i>(length=9)</i>
      <i>public</i> 'Port' <font color='#888a85'>=&gt;</font> <small>string</small> <font color='#cc0000'>'25575'</font> <i>(length=5)</i>
      <i>public</i> '_Sock' <font color='#888a85'>=&gt;</font> <b>resource</b>(<i>4</i><font color='#2e3436'>,</font> <i>stream</i>)
      <i>public</i> '_Id' <font color='#888a85'>=&gt;</font> <small>int</small> <font color='#4e9a06'>1</font>
    </pre>
```

---

This is essentially what I'm trying to do:

1. Create an RCON connection to a Minecraft server by sending a $.post request to PHP, which will establish the connection.
2. Return a response ("Authenticated" or "Authentication failed") to indicate success and the created object for later use (to avoid creating multiple connections.)
3. Send commands through this already-created RCON object by returning it to the JS $.post and storing it in a variable on the page.

All of the above will be done via one .php page and the output is alerted and printed to a textarea (which occasionally doesn't work at all.)

Comment: `json_encode($data)` -- well, what is `$data` exactly? Did you read the documentation for `json_encode`?

Comment: Mistakenly typed the wrong variable - fixed now.

Comment: Can you show the output from `var_dump($r)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) states, you cannot encode resource types with `json_encode`. The current code attempts to do this because the class `minecraftRcon` exposes the property `$_Sock` whose value is a resource.

However, it's not clear exactly why your JS/PHP code is not working as a whole. Since you can't access (or even see) anything "inside" a resource value from PHP it's almost certain that you are not trying to do that from JS, so while the warning is valid and you should fix it, it probably does not bear at all on your current problem.

Comment: I see. This is essentially what I'm trying to do: (1) create an RCON connection to a Minecraft server by sending a $.post request to PHP, which will establish the connection. (2) Return a response ("Authenticated" or "Authentication failed") to indicate success and the created object for later use (to avoid creating multiple connections.) (3) Send commands through this already-created RCON object.

Comment: How can I preserve the minecraftRcon? Is it impossible?

Comment: @CarsonWilber: The idea of returning the RCON to JS is not realizable; RCON is a PHP object backed by PHP code, JS cannot touch that at all. If you wanted to preserve some costly-to-compute but ultimately "dumb" data across requests you could do it using a session variable, but in this case you want to preserve a TCP connection. That is simply not possible in PHP unless you are using an [application server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_application_servers#PHP).

Comment: Establishing the connection each time is no problem, it's just an annoyance to the server in general. I suppose I will have to work with a model that establishes the connection for each command - very unfortunate. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can't just encode an object directly in `json_encode()`.

You need to convert your object to an array, you could use something like:

`$data = get_object_vars($r)`

And encode `$data`

Comment: Is `minecraftRcon` a custom class? Try creating a function within the class which exports `get_object_vars()` - and encode `$r->getArray();` or whatever it is that you name your function.

Comment: @Ryan - this isn't actually right is it? json_encode should be able to encode any PHP object - but it'll only include publicly accessible class members.

Comment: @CD001 I may be wrong but I thought `json_encode` couldn't encode objects?

Comment: Using ... function getData() { return get_object_vars($this); } ... and ... return json_encode($r->getData()); ... I receive the same error: unsupported. ... gettype($r->getData()); ... returns 'array'. I am clueless. As Jon said, though, the value of $_Sock is a resource, therefore it will not be encoded.

Comment: Here is essentially what I wish to do: preserve an @fsockopen by passing it back to the $.post request in order to prevent opening multiple connections to an RCON server.

Comment: @Ryan I just cobbled up a quick script to test (as I wasn't 100% certain), `json_encode` will happy encode both `StdClass` objects and custom objects - and yes, it does only include public class members in the JSON ;)